# OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand - Invalid authorization specification

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oledb, oledbconnection

I have a single `DBF file` which I can open using `Microsoft Visual FoxPro` and I now need to add through `Visual Studio 2012` in `C#` lnauage data to it.

I'm getting this error: `Invalid authorization specification.`

with this code:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to submit?", "Potvrzení", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        odcCON.Open();
        OleDbCommand odc = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO netpokl.DBF (Castka,Akce) values(@castka,@akce)");
        odc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@castka",textBox2.Text);
        odc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@akce",test);
        odc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        odcCON.Close();

    }
```

OleDbConnection is this:

```
 OleDbConnection odcCON = new OleDbConnection(" Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=\\SERVER\\Transfer\netpokl.DBF");
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the security information on the connection string.  Something like this "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=yes"

Comment: Add a `User Id=XYZ` property. I got the same error after reusing a connection string that wasn't intended for ole db. Changing the `User=XYZ` to `User Id=XYZ` fixed it. You may also decide to use windows authentication, in which case you can add `Integrated Security=SSPI` and remove the `User Id` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read/write dbase files you can use the Microsoft JET OLEDB provider, with a connection string that looks like this one:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\directory;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=
```

Note that Data Source is the folder where your dbase file is.
Finally in your query the table name should be the file name without the .dbf extension, like this:

```
INSERT INTO netpokl (Castka,Akce) values(@castka,@akce)
```

Should you need this to work on a 64bit application you can use the Microsoft ACE OLEDB provider ([Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255))

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;Data Source=c:\directory;
```